# ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [core/duplicate-app] A Firebase App named "[DEFAULT]" already exists

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Since im new in firebase, im having trouble with duplicated name already exists, and i need your help.

```
E/flutter (21802): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [core/duplicate-app] A Firebase App named "[DEFAULT]" already exists
E/flutter (21802): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp
package:firebase_core_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:111
E/flutter (21802): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21802): #1      Firebase.initializeApp
package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:41
E/flutter (21802): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21802): #2      main
package:flutterbuyandsell/main.dart:47
E/flutter (21802): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21802):
```

**…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:111**

[image: Method_channel_firebase]

**package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:41**

[image: Firebase.dart]

**package:flutterbuyandsell/main.dart:47**

[image: firebase on main.dart]

Comment: Do not post images as a code. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In my case, the problem was on iOS whereas the Android is fine. Apparently iOS and Android have different configurations, so I changed my iOS configuration in Firebase.initializeApp block.

Answer (score 77):

I solved the issue by adding a name to the initializeApp method:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  name: 'name-here',
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
)
```

I used the same name used in the firebase console as my project ID for consistency, keep in mind that you cannot add spaces to the name (only dashes `-`).

Comment: Thanks, this one worked for me. can you explain what exactly happens? why does it work when we mention the name. in the previous versions it's just worked with the option param only.

Comment: This worked for me, The Issue happened after adding a variant build that uses a different Firebase project and running flutterfire. This is what I did


```
var firebaseOptions = (config.environment == Environment.prod ||
          config.environment == Environment.beta)
      ? prod.DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform
      : DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform;
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: firebaseOptions.projectId, options: firebaseOptions);
```

Comment: It saves my lot of hours... :)

Comment: FYI, this answer is just a workaround—Matthew Trent's solution below is the actual solution that doesn't require code modifications and rectifies the actual problem—a misalignment of configuration files.

Answer (score 23):

## If you used FlutterFire, this is the proper solution:

This solution should work for you if any of the values (like `projectId`/`PROJECT_ID`,`apiKey`/`API_KEY`, etc.) in this file: `ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist` don't match the info in this file: `firebase_options.dart`. This means your Firebase initialization of the second app messed up somehow, so, we need to fix it.

**From your project root, run these commands sequentially:**

Remove the file containing Firebase info that possibly wasn't updated properly via FlutterFire:

```bash
rm ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist
```

Run configure to re-create the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file:

```bash
flutterfire configure
```

Clean your build:

```bash
flutter clean
```

Get dependencies again after cleaning:

```bash
flutter pub get
```

Run your app (*from scratch, no hot-reloading!*):

```bash
flutter run
```

Comment: This should be the first thing that people check (that their plist file matches their firebase_options.dart). Everything above is more of a hack to fix the issue if this doesn't work. In my case, I didn't call flutterfire configure again, I just manually changed the values in my plist file to match.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Duplicated firebase names issue can happen if you have multiple Firebase projects installed

Comment: I agree with other comments. This should be the first answer. Other answers are misleading, as explicitly setting a name for Firebase app is for a situation where you want to add more than one Firebase project to your app.

Answer (score 15):

```
flutter clean
```

and

```
flutter pub get
```

executing these two commands consecutively solved my problem.

Comment: The reason it may have worked is because other Firebase config was added before. So by cleaning and getting project old resources are eliminated.

Answer (score 8):

Add this in Flutter

NOTE - Use this "Firebase.initializeApp" only Once in the entire Project.

// Wait for Default Firebase app to initialize

```
if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
  name: 'YourAPP',
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
 ).whenComplete(() {
  print("completedAppInitialize");
 });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue by adding the name of my Firebase project. You can try this:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  name: 'name of your App in FireStore',
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by changing your `main.dart` file as below:

```
void main() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: '<YourAppName>',
      options: FirebaseOptions(
          apiKey: '<apiKey>',
          appId: '<appId>',
          messagingSenderId: '<senderId>',
          projectId: '<projectId>'));

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

This worked for me, I believe it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: firebaseprojectname,
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
          apiKey: firebaseApiKey,
          appId: firebaseAppId,
          messagingSenderId: firebasemMssagingSenderId,
          projectId: firebaseProjectId),
    );
  }
```

add the following in your main.dart file inside `main()`

Answer (score 1):

###### I have two solutions which I have tested personally and they both worked:

**First Solution:**

Just clean the project using `flutter clean` and run it again, it should now work!

---

**Second Solution:**

1. Comment the Initialization of Firebase in the main method.
2. Run the App.
3. Once the app is running, stop it.
4. Uncomment the same initialization code.
5. Run the App.

That's it

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
 }
```

Comment: Even this only sometimes works

Answer (score 0):

if you make changes to your options while you run the app with `flutter run -d chrome` and you use just hot reload after you made your changes to the options, it tries to initialise a second app, which doesn't work. Just terminate your running session with `ctrl+c` and start a fresh session, the error will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the proposed options and none worked to the full extent. Adding the name parameter to `Firebase.initializeApp()` is rather a workaround then a fix. Giving a name there also creates a new issue for running the Flutter app in the web, so it becomes a vicious circle.

The fix seems to be super easy:

1. change sdk version in your pubspec.yaml file like this

```
'>=3.0.0 <4.0.0'
```

I had it set up before to '>=2.19.4 <3.0.0'.

2. Clean and run again:

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get
```

P.S. If that doesn't help. Try deleting (or resetting) your pubscep.yaml file and `flutter clean` and then put the pubspec.yaml to the previous version.